# VBA add array to a list

Tags: arrays, vba

```
Sub RangeBulkAmend()

   Set list = list.CreateInstance
     Dim c As Range
      Dim i As Long
      Dim myarr() As Variant

      For Each c In Selection

           list.Add c.value     
       Next c

            ReDim myarr(list.Count - 1)

         For i = 1 To list.Count - 1
             myarr(i) = list.Items(i)
             msg = msg & vbCrLf & myarr(i)

          Next i



          {{ListWindow.ListBox1.list = myarr}}

             Load ListWindow

             ListWindow.Show
end sub
```

i have an error on the compile as I try to pass my array to a list the code with double braces that where the compiler points too but if I highlight i get the message Object variable or With block variable not set any help will be gladly appreciated thank you
 in advance please note the list refereed to in the code above is my own custom list the issue is sending the array to the list box at the double braces checked the code it produces something now to extract that to a list box

Comment: You could skip one loop by loading the array first `myarr=selection.Value` then looping through it to load your list, using `for i = LBound(myarr) to Ubound(myarr)`.  this is not the answer but a suggestion.

Comment: stab in the dark here...set the list after you call Load ListWindow. More than likely the control does not yet exist.

Comment: It seems that you are using 1 as the `UBound` of your array (which is not VBA default). So you might want to add `Option Base 1` to your VBA module (above / before all subs).

Comment: also...what data type is the variable list? where is it declared?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions none of them work I get error 380 when i try these suggestions if any one knows how I can set my array then maybe that will help

Comment: This looks more like VB.Net than VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only your intention to load a list box with the selected cells values then:

```
Sub RangeBulkAmend()

    Dim myarr() As Variant

    myarr = Selection.Value

    Load ListWindow
    ListWindow.ListBox1.List = myarr
    ListWindow.Show
End Sub
```

Will do it

Or for that matter simply skipping the whole and just assigning the selection.Value to the listbox also works:

```
Sub RangeBulkAmend()

    Load ListWindow
    ListWindow.ListBox1.List = Selection.Value
    ListWindow.Show
End Sub
```

To mass add to an existing list in a list box try this:

```
Sub RangeBulkAmend()
    Load ListWindow
    Dim myarr() As Variant
    Dim oldarr() As Variant
    Dim t&, i&

    myarr = Selection.Value

    t = ListWindow.ListBox1.ListCount

    ReDim oldarr(0 To (ListWindow.ListBox1.ListCount + UBound(myarr, 1) - 1)) As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(oldarr)
        If i < ListWindow.ListBox1.ListCount Then
            oldarr(i) = ListWindow.ListBox1.List(i)
        Else
            oldarr(i) = myarr(i - t + 1, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    ListWindow.ListBox1.List = oldarr
    ListWindow.Show modal
End Sub
```